# The curious case of NSFileCoordinator in Swift

Tags: swift, nsfilecoordinator

It seems that NSFileCoordinator, despite being a pretty important class, has not been given any Swiftification. It has not been given any `async` alternative; you have to provide a completion handler. Moreover, it takes an NSErrorPointer rather than being marked `throws`, and the pointee cannot be referred to inside the completion handler:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "fakepath")
var error: NSError?
NSFileCoordinator().coordinate(readingItemAt: url, error: &error) { url in
    let theError = error
    print(theError as Any)
}
```

This results in an error: "Simultaneous accesses to `error`, but modification requires exclusive access."

If I can't access the error from inside the block, what use is it? How am I supposed to access it? Surely not *after* the block; the completion handler is called asynchronously (because we have to wait until coordinated access is possible), so after the block, the error will always be `nil` even if there was in fact an error.

(I notice that [Apple's own example code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/providing_access_to_directories) skirts this issue by never checking the value of its `error` variable at all.)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this method is even weirder than I thought. According to the docs, if there *is* an error, the completion handler is *never called*. Thus, checking `error` for a non-`nil` value after the completion handler might actually be somewhat useful.

Moreover, the docs also say that you are expected to set a separate "sentinel" value to indicate failure initially and then set it to indicate success within the completion handler. So the canonical architecture would be:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "fakepath")
var failure = true
var error: NSError?
NSFileCoordinator().coordinate(readingItemAt: url, error: &error) { url in
    failure = false
}
if failure {
    print(error as Any)
}
```

I've never actually seen this architecture used, but that appears to be what you're supposed to do.

Comment: You say in your question "the completion handler is called asynchronously". It's actually not asynchronous; the closure parameter is non-escaping, so it must be called synchronously. This is why it's fine to check the value of `error` after the call to `coordinate(readingItemAt: ...)`. (Also, I don't know why Apple suggests to use a sentinel value when you can just check if the error is nil or not. Maybe it's possible for `error` to still be nil if the coordination fails for some obscure reason?)

Comment: I think you're right; maybe the call just blocks, plain and simple, and then either calls the handler or skips it, and we proceed to the next lines. That might be a good reason to run on a background thread. You might want to give that as answer. The documentation is astoundingly hard to understand. I tried but failed to find good examples, even though we are told to always use a file coordinator in a UIDocumentPickerControllerDelegate (which is how this arose for me).

Comment: Wondering if at least should be doing something like

```
extension NSFileCoordinator {
  func coordinate(writingTo: URL, onSuccess: (URL) -> Void) throws {
    var error: NSError? = nil
    coordinate(writingItemAt: writingTo, error: &error, byAccessor: onSuccess)
    if let error {
      throw error
    }
  }
}
```

But probably if this does block there is some much nicer approach with modern Swift.